# Proper way of writing an int array and returning the number of elements?

Tags: java, arrays, return

I have a problem. I am trying to write a value-returning method that returns the number of elements in an integer array. I have the array written and have the return statement half right. I am lost at this point. how to I get the number of elements in the array, which is 9, into an int form and into the return statement?
Thank you

```
public class ChapterEightCode 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) 
  {
      int eTotals = myArray();

      System.out.println(eTotals);
  }

  static int myArray()
  {
     int[] intArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

     for (int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++)
     {
        System.out.println(intArray[i]); 
     }

     int eTotals = 1000;
     return eTotals;
  }
}
```

Comment: Int total = IntArray.length; ?? Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you are looping if you're just after the array length, try this:

```
return intArray.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the length field of the array:

```
return intArray.length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Observe this method carefully:

You're first creating an integer array, then looping through each element from 0 to length of `intArray`, printing the elements one by one. Then you declare an integer `eTotals`, set it to `1000` and then return `eTotals` which means, you're returning `1000` *all* the time.

```
   static int myArray()
  {
     int[] intArray = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

     for (int i=0; i<intArray.length; i++)
     {
        System.out.println(intArray[i]); 
     }

     int eTotals = 1000;
     return eTotals; // instead `return intArray.length;`
  }
```

Why not just `return intArray.length;`?

Comment: THANK YOU! I keep over thinking it and trying to convert it into a string and then trying to get the string back into an int inside the main method. I really appreciate you showing me that I should think SIMPLE.

Comment: @Torre, lesser the no. of lines of code, faster your program will run. And more time you'll have, socializing :-)

Answer (score 0):

if u write a "int eTotals = 1000; return eTotals;" in the last of the function myArray(),I will fell that the code before  has no meaning。
Maybe u can try replace the statement "int eTotals=1000;" as "int eTotals = intArray.length;"